# Textboxes and array C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I will have single-dimensional array, how can I fill all this textboxes with different index of this array?

For example:

```
int[] array1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] array2 = new int[] { 4, 5, 6 };
int[] array3 = new int[] { 7, 8, 9 };
```

[image: Textboxes]

Anyone have any advice? Thank you

Comment: array have 5 elements where as you have 9 textboxes. how you want to map items in array with textbox and which order ?

Comment: I meant something like that. Question Edited

Comment: Please try to formulate your question more clearly.

Comment: @progNewbie : what is not clear in question ?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal Well, maybe it is just me. But I don't really get what he is trying to do. He is talking about 'this textboxes' but I dont know which textboxes he is talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your text boxes in an array:

```
var boxes = new TextBox[,]
{
     { textbox1, textbox2, textbox3 },
     { textbox4, textbox5, textbox6 },
     { textbox7, textbox8, textbox9 },
};
```

And your data too:

```
var data = new int[][]
{
    array1, array2, array3
};
```

And then set them in a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
         boxes[i,j].Text = data[i][j].ToString();
```

Note that, there are two different types of two dimensional arrays. First one represents a 3x3 array of text boxes, while the second one is actually a one-dimensional array of int[] values.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it